# I can't seem to use the DateTimeField in django without errors

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My django blog app has the parameters, title, pub-date, body and image. when i create a blog model on the admin page i get an error. here's what the code looks like.

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/blog/blog/add/
column "pub_date" is of type integer but expression is of type timestamp with time zone
LINE 1: ..._date", "image", "body") VALUES ('My first blog', '2020-04-0...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Here is the model i created:

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    body = models.TextField()
```

Comment: What query do you make?

Comment: please explain... i'm just learning django

Comment: Found a solution. I used the `objects = models.Manager()` in the class